# Facebook SDK is not a dylib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am attempting to build a project I did not write, and I keep reaching this error:

ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/my_user_name/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit', framework linker option at /Users/my_user_name/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit is not a dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAppEvents", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is a new error since updating Parse and Bolts pods. Other solutions for Auto-Linking that I've seen on here have not been able to help, but since the update to Facebook SDK is new perhaps someone has already solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the conflict between the reference of FB SDK located at `/Users/my_user_name/Documents/` and the one in CocoaPods.

Originally I used FB SDK located at `/Users/my_user_name/Documents/` as suggested in [FB SDK Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) tutorial. Then switched to Cocoapods after I started using `react-native`.

The solution is to remove Facebook SDK references from your apps `Frameworks` folder in `YourApp.xcodeproj`. I have explained more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36947791/556678.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're using a current version of the FBSDK! Also make sure you followed THESE (new) instructions: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users (because with the parse update different things must be done!).

If the problem persists, I suggest you build a new project (that follows the instructions in the previous link).